# angular factory for $http service makes call twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I created an angular factory for $http service. I am getting the response and able to use the same in the controller but the problem is, when i check the network tab in the browser, the http request is made twice

Factory:

```
app.factory('myService', function ($http, $q) {

var deferred = $q.defer();
var responseData = null;
var obj = {};

obj.getData = function(){
    $http.get('test.json').success(function(response){
        responseData = response;
        deferred.resolve(responseData);
    }).error(function(response){
        deferred.reject(responseData);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

obj.myData = function(){
    return responseData;
}

return obj;
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope,myService){

myService.getData().then(function(){
   $scope.myDetails = myService.myData();
});

});
```

what's wrong in my approach. Please provide me a solution

Comment: though i won't do it like this, everything is fine to me there. Are ou sure you didn't bind "myController" twice in your application ?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are making your caching scenario is quite complicated and not really helpful. How do you know if  data has already been loaded?

Maybe you can create a simple Caching Service to handle your caching at a single point (nr of code lines will go down).

```
angular.module("YourApp").factory("CachingService", [
    "$q",
    "$http",
    function ($q, $http,) {
        var cache = {};

        return {
            getFromCache: getFromCache
        };


        function getFromCache(url) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if (cache[url]) {
                deferred.resolve(cache[url]);
            } else {
                return $http.get(url).then(function (result) {
                    cache[url] = result;
                    return result;
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
     }
 ]);
```

And then, you simply call it inside your other service :

```
angular.module("YourApp").factory("myService", [
    "CachingService",
    function(CachingService){
        return {
             getData: getData
        };

        function getData(){
            return CachingService.getFromCache("test.json");
        }
    }
]);
```

And then, inside your controller :

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope,myService){

    myService.getData().then(function(result){
       $scope.myDetails = result.Data;
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can return `$http` not `deferred.promise`

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, it's quite short and I think it could be expanded to describe why and how this answers the question.